# python function to perform timing on generic code and write it to log file

Tags: logging, timing

Everytime I want to write to log how long it takes to run some code I wrap the code in the following way

```
logger.info('Running   <MYCODE>' )
start_time = time.time()
 <MYCODE>
logger.info("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

This makes the code very, very unreadable very, very soon.

I know the %timeit thing, but I think here it does not apply because I want to log and because I do not want to run it N times to get a variance or stuff like that.

I was thinking I should define a function

```
def timing ( <MYCODE> ):
    logger.info('Running   <MYCODE>' )
    start_time = time.time()
    <MYCODE>
    logger.info("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

but I am not sure this is a good idea. Firstly because looks like a problem a lot of people already encoutered and solved better than my 5 minutes solution, secondly because I have to handle the return of this function ... what does it return? and how do I pass the whole piece of code I want to run? I am very confused, looks like there is some decorator people have already written for this ...

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import inspect

def timed(f:callable):
    start = time.time()
    ret = f()
    elapsed = 1000*(time.time() - start)
    source_code=inspect.getsource(f).strip('\n') 
    logger.info(source_code+":  "+str(elapsed)+" seconds")
    return ret
```

can be used by

```
a = timed(lambda: np.sin(np.pi))
```